# NSAssert doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, assert, nsassert

I'm trying to use `NSAssert` in my code but it doesn't do a thing.

In this piece of code, the assertion should fail but doesn't:

```
    MSLog(@"cross.obj = %@",[cross obj]);
    NSAssert([cross obj]!=nil,@"[cross obj] == nil");
```

The output of this is:

> cross.obj = (null)

**What could be the problem?**

Comment: For some reason `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` blocks assertions from functioning. Try deleting the definition.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is that there is a difference between a `nil` and a `null` value.

So please check it  with other examples.

It will work.

Comment: nil and NULL are same values. Instead, [NSNull null] is object with non-nil value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the result from `[cross obj]` is `[NSNull null]`, not `nil`.

The output probably is `<null>` which does not mean `NULL` or `nil` but the `NSNull` singleton object. This object is used as a placeholder where `nil` is not an option (for instance in `NSArray`s).

Another reason might be that the `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` preprocessor macro is defined which disables `NSAssert`.

Comment: `[cross obj]!=nil` evaluates to `FALSE`